# Specify dependency for Maven extension

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-extension

I'm trying to configure `org.springframework.build:aws-maven:jar:4.2.0.RELEASE` for a project, but stuck in the following problem: seems that some of plugin dependecies requires `org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl`, but can't find. Failing with:

```
Unresolveable build extension: 
Plugin org.springframework.build:aws-maven:4.2.0.RELEASE or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: 
Failed to collect dependencies for org.springframework.build:aws-maven:jar:4.2.0.RELEASE (): 
No versions available for org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:[1.8,1.9) within specified range -> [Help 2]
```

I've added a repository containing this artefact, and also tried to add it as dependency to main project (btw, I don't need it actually). Doesn't help.

It's extension, not just plugin, so I can't add dependency there:

```
<build>
    <extensions>
        <extension>
            <groupId>org.springframework.build</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-maven</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </extension>
    </extensions>
</build>
```

As I understand, build extension don't use dependencies from main block. How can I specify this dependency for extension?

Comment: Where did you add this repository? In your POM? In your Maven Repository Manager such as Nexus?

Comment: Run `mvn` again with `-X` and try to see where is it trying to resolve the dependency from.

Comment: @Betoverse thanks for idea, seems that it's because `maven-metadata.xml` for `jackson-core-asl` is broken.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was because of invalid `maven-metadata.xml` on `http://central.maven.org/maven2` repository (wtf?).

Fixed by removing downloaded file (`rm -rf ~/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jackson`) and using `mirrors.ibiblio.org` repository:

```
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>ibiblio.mirrors</id>
        <url>http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/maven2</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```